# Google play debug purchase

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in google play alpha testing. 
I'm a tester as well. 
The issue is I'm not able to debug the purchase flow.
I read all the posts here in `Stackoverflow` and nothing helped.
Sometimes I'm receiving errors like: "This version of the application is not configured for billing" or "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found" although My versionCode and VersionName are the same as in Google play console. 
I'm also added to build.gradle in the buildTypes{}:

```
minifyEnabled false
debuggable true
```

And to the Manifest:

```
android:debuggable="true"
tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode"
```

Can someone provide a Step by step explanation on how to debug a Google play purchase?

Comment: It is unclear why you are providing your gradle build types here. 

Were you able to perform purchases on a dev/staging environment and the problem occurs in a production environment?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Many examples are shown that we need to add those lines to the build.gradle buildTypes. Tha's why I added them here to avoid answers with solutions I already tried.
I'm able to purchase only when I download the app from the Play store. In all other ways, I'm getting those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check "Release management" -> "App signing" in Play store console. You should use same app signing key as your debug's. Google play would generate one automatically by itself if you don't upload yours. Just request updating it.